# Will function pointers always initialize to NULL?

Tags: c++, c

I'm using MSVC and it seems like the code below does not crash and the function pointer is initialized to NULL by the compiler.

```
int (*operate)(int a, int b);
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int main()
{


    if(operate) //would crash here if not NULL
    {
        cout << operate(5,5);
    }

    operate = add;
    if(operate)
    {
        cout << operate(5,5);
    }

    operate = subtract;
    if(operate)
    {
        cout << operate(5,5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So it seems MSVC initializes function pointers to NULL, but if I build this on gcc in Linux would it also be NULL? Is it conventional or MSVC specific, can I rely on it being NULL wherever I go?

Thanks

Comment: Make the pointer a local variable and you'll see that it won't.  You have an uninitialized global and the compiler will usually put that in the [`.bss`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment which is zero-initialized.

Comment: C or C++, they're different languages.

Comment: @Jeff: where the compiler puts it is irrelevant. It's required to be zero-initialized if it has static storage duration.

Comment: I just solved my issue, memset saves the day!

Comment: @R..: That I didn't know (until seeing j_random_hacker's update).  In the context of C, I don't know if the standard requires it but what I said could have explained why it _happens to be_ zero initially which is to be true (AFAIK) for most if not all modern compilers.

Comment: Compare with [Will a function pointer be NULL by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877495/2509) (which is not a duplicate, but is relevant and shows that Milo needs to work a little more on his question titles).

Comment: @Jeff: Of course the standard requires it, and has for 20-some years. This is one of the most basic things any C programmer should know.

Comment: @R...: And I'm sure anyone who has a copy of the standard would know that.  I don't have a copy.  ;)  I just never really worried about whether or not the standard requires what values uninitialized variables have, just that I shouldn't use it until I explicitly initialize it.  But now I know ("and knowing is half the battle") so that's always good to know.  :)

Comment: Here is the latest (C99) standard plus amendments up through TC3: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`operate` is initialised to NULL because it is a global variable, not because it is a function pointer.  All objects with static storage duration (which includes global variables, file-level `static` variables and `static` variables in functions) are initialised to 0 or NULL if no initialiser is given.

**[EDIT in response to Jim Buck's comment:]**
In C++, this is guaranteed by clause 3.6.2/1 of the language standard, which begins:

> Objects with static storage duration
>   (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized
>   (8.5) before any other initialization
>   takes place. Zero-initialization and
>   initialization with a constant
>   expression are collectively called
>   *static initialization*; all other
>   initialization is *dynamic
>   initialization*.

I expect the same behaviour is true of C, since C++ is designed to be compatible with it on most things, although I don't have the standard for it.

**[EDIT #2]** As Jeff M points out in a comment, it's important to realise that variables of automatic storage duration (that is, "ordinary" local variables) are *not* automatically zero-initialised: unless an initialiser is given, or they are assigned values by a constructor, they will initially contain random garbage (whatever was already sitting in memory at that location).  So it's a good habit to initialise all variables -- it can't hurt but can help.

Comment: Global/static variables are not guaranteed to be zero-initialized. They might in a debug build, but even that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Jim: Indeed they are so guaranteed in C++.  I will add a reference to the relevant paragraph from the standard to my post.

Comment: My comment on the question might be relevant.  "You have an uninitialized global and the compiler will usually put that in the [`.bss`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment which is zero-initialized."

Comment: @Jeff: whether or not the compiler chooses to put them in the `.bss` segment, they **must** be initially zero. This is required by both the C and C++ language standards.

Comment: @R.. I thought it was this way also, this answer seems to suggest that for C it is otherwise...

Comment: The C99 spec section 6.9.2 covers this -- its the same as C++

Comment: @Matt: Not sure how you came away with the impression that I was suggesting things are different for C.  I was just saying I was not certain it was the same.  Dunno how I could have been much clearer about that...?

Comment: Hmm, then this is new since the PlayStation development days (uh-oh, I'm dating myself).. stuff was sure not zero-initialized in a release build back then. That was fun-for-everyone the night of a gold master.

Comment: @Jim: I can see why that stuck in your memory :)  C++ compilers have been notorious for implementing the language spec incorrectly -- my guess is a compiler or linker bug caused you that grief.  Don't know if that makes it better or worse... :)

Comment: Worse, always worse! :) Actually, it was gcc 3.x that was being used at the time for PlayStation development.

Comment: In all fairness, we should describe that as "Sony's compiler based on GCC 3". Can't blame the Gnu people for all the weirdness in that compiler". The Sony of America people I met back in 2003 were very apologetic for that.